# What is Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA)?

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble to understand the following:

In the Fisher’s Linear Discrimination analysis, the idea was to base the discriminant rule on a projection $a^Tx$ such that a good separation was achieved. Now, I don't understand why $a^Tx$ is a projection? Isn't it just a linear combination?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know. If you don't get any answers here, you might try asking on the statistics website, crossvalidated (there should be a link to it on this page). But be sure to leave a link at each site to the question at the other site.

Comment: $a^Tx$ is the dot product of $a$ and $x$ and the magnitude of the dot product is the magnitude of the component of $a$ on $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by the magnitude of a scalar? $a^Tx$ is a scalar.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is there different site for statistics where we can share our ideas?

Comment: You mean, different from the one I told you about, ADAM?

Comment: I mean both if you know any. Thanks!

Comment: How many statistics sites do you need, ADAM? Try the one I told you about, and if you don't get a useful answer there, then it's time to look for another one (or think about improving your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, $a^Tx$ is a linear combination or weighted sum.  And, if $a$ is a unit vector, then $a^Tx$ is also the scalar projection of $x$ onto $a.$  And this is the interpretation that is used in two-class LDA, where $a$ provides the projection direction.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [Fisher Linear Discriminant by Olga Veksler](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eoveksler/Courses/CS434a_541a/Lecture8.pdf) for good introduction.